# check if a variable equal a number in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

I m doing aan exercice in a tutoriel in **Angularjs** . I want to check if a variable **nbElement** in scope equal 5   change **curentpage** to 1000. but curentpage never change.

controller.js :

```
  var app=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
  app.controller("CategController",function($scope, $http){
      $scope.curentpage=0;
      $scope.nbElement=5;
      $scope.delete=function(p){
      if ((parseInt($scope.nbElement)==parseInt("5")) 
        {
          $scope.curentpage=1000; 
        }

      }
   });
```

I tried   `if ($scope.nbElement==5)`     and   `if ((parseInt($scope.nbElement,10)==parseInt("5",10))`  but didn t work either .

Comment: I am not sure, why are you parsing your model value and "5" as I believe both are integer value. you can simply do like this : `$scope.nbElement===5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided extra `(` in your condition.

```
if ((parseInt($scope.nbElement)==parseInt("5")) 
    ^
   here
```

Just remove it.

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/mxafovoj/3/)**</kbd>

Moreover, you don't need this type of `int` checking

```
if ((parseInt($scope.nbElement)==parseInt("5"))
```

as value of `nbElement` int, you don't need one.

Just put it

```
if ($scope.nbElement == 5)
```

However, if value of `nbElement` changes to string, if you put int on right side of condition it'll do casting during checking. But if you wanna to do strict checking, use `===` instead of `==`  and add `+` before variable it'll convert value into the number

Like this

```
if (+$scope.nbElement === 5) {
```